# Rows as a Wrap's children. How to do it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to wrap the few Rows with `Wrap`. The reason is to make sure that any row is not overflowing.

Here's my code:

```
Wrap(
  children: [
    Row(
      children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.cake,
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 3),
        Text(
          'variable text',
        ),
        Text(
          'variable text',
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Row(
      children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.flight,
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 3),
        Text(
          'variable text',
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Row(
      children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.transgender,
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 3),
        Text(
          'variable text',
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

And it doesn't act like a Wrap, All children are in column, instead of one after another.

As I can imagine the problem is with using the `Raw` widget inside. I am doing this because I need to have `Icon` just before the `Text`, as like prefixIcon. So I place Icon and Text in one Row.

Can you suggest me any way how can Row be a child of the Wrap? Or maybe I can solve my problem in other way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

A horizontal Wrap will constrain its children to be at most as wide as the Wrap itself.  By default, a Row with bounded width will take up the entire width allowed.  To override this default, you can give the Row `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`.

```dart
Wrap(
  children: [
    Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        // ...
      ],
    ),
    // More rows...
  ],
),
```

Comment: That is something that I was missing. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flex widget instead of using Wrap, Flex widget also can help you to achieve not overflowing issue. The code should be below:

```
 body: Flex(
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      children: [
        Row( ... ),
        Row( ... ),
        Row( ... ),
      ],
 ),
```